# Сбивается ориентация картинки, загруженной из библиотеки через uiimagepickercontroller

Tags: objective-c

Привет!

При загрузке картинки из библиотеки и вставке её во вью через uiimagepickercontroller сбивается ориентация картинки, переворачивается на 90deg против часовой. Также некоторые картинки вставляются нормально. Причём значение imageOrientation для перевёрнутой картинки и той, что вставляется нормально, возвращается одинаковое. Пробовал задавать uiimageorientationup, но не выходит.

Как решить эту проблему, чтобы картинки фиксированно вставлялись в портретной ориентации?

Comment: @x3zone, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Да это известная проблема, решение [тут](https://gist.github.com/alex-cellcity/1531596).